# How to get DroneDeploy Flight ID for the Plan programmatically?

Tags: javascript, dronedeploy

***Prelude:***
  From what I learned about DroneDeploy API here: 
  http://developer.dronedeploy.com/applications, there is no possibility to get 
  Flight ID from `dronedeployApi.Plans.getCurrentlyViewed()` object. Though, I see 
  that it is the only unique value which goes with Export-ready emails and could 
  be perfect foreign key.

***Question:*** how to get value of the Flight ID associated with particular plan programmatically?

Comment: What do you mean by flight id? PlanID refers to a map through all phases of the workflow: planning, flying, and the exported map.

Comment: @ramblinjan, once a user gets email notification with export download link, he can see "Flight Number" and "Export ID". "Flight Number" is the same for any export emails on the plan - that is what I mean by Flight ID. Alternatively, is it possible to include PlanID in the body of email notifications?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to not utilize the flight id. As far as the email is concerned, the user should already know what plan they have based on their own context. As far as your system is concerned, it is really recommended that you utilize webhooks, and embed relevant data in the webhook url. i.e.

`` `https://myddapp.heroku.com/exports/{plan.id}/{some_other_identifiable information}` ``

You should also get an export.id in the body of the POST request, this should aid in further uniqueness.

- Experience: I am a DroneDeploy engineer.

Comment: Webhook is the option we are moving towards, APIs to be ready soon, I was thinking of using Flight IDs as temporary solution.